# arduino web client uploading data to mysql database

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I have got this quick sketch that post data to mysql db using php add.php module.

```
#include <SFE_BMP180.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include<dht.h>
dht DHT;

// You will need to create an SFE_BMP180 object, here called "pressure":
SFE_BMP180 bmp;

#define DHT11_PIN 2

double tempInC;
int humidity;

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);
char server[] = "192.168.1.3";

EthernetClient client;
byte php_server[] = {192 , 168 , 1 , 3};

long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
long interval = 250000; // READING INTERVAL

String data;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  if (bmp.begin()) {
    Serial.println("BMP init Success");
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }

  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");
  data = "";
}

void loop() {
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  char status;
  status = bmp.startTemperature();
  if (status != 0) {
    delay(status);
    status = bmp.getTemperature(tempInC);
  }
  else Serial.println("error retrieving temperature measurement\n");

  humidity = DHT.humidity;
  data = "?temp1=" + String(tempInC) + "&hum1=" + String(humidity);

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.print("connected. My IP is ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
    client.println("POST /arduino/add.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.1.3");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(data.length());
    client.println();
    client.print(data);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
  Serial.println(data);
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  if (client.connected()) {
    client.stop();  // DISCONNECT FROM THE SERVER
  }
  delay(300000); // WAIT FOR A WHILE BEFORE SENDING AGAIN
}
```

but its not updating the database, using the below **add.php** file from arduino **web-client.ino**

```
<?php
        include("connect.php");

        $link=Connection();

        $temp1=$_POST["temp1"];
        $hum1=$_POST["hum1"];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `tempLog` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
                VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$hum1."')"; 

        mysql_query($query,$link);
        mysql_close($link);

        header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

i checked in mysql prompt which is also the result displayed if I open the server url : 192.168.1.3/arduino/index.php

```
mysql> select * from tempLog;
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| timeStamp           | temperature | humidity |
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| 2016-11-28 11:50:37 |           0 |        0 |
| 2016-11-28 12:30:25 |           0 |        0 |
+---------------------+-------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't know how the first entry got created but second one I created by manually executing the url 192.168.1.3/arduino/add.php?temp1=26.64&hum1=18

the index page is showing he data from db as shown above in sql, that means connection is established and mysql and table is fetched from correct db. i.e. *arduinoSensorData*  in my case.

my serial monitor window got updated:

```
BMP init Success
connecting...
connected. My IP is 192.168.1.131
?temp1=26.64&hum1=18
connected. My IP is 192.168.1.131
?temp1=26.64&hum1=18
connected. My IP is 192.168.1.131
?temp1=26.57&hum1=18
```

which means arduino is not able to put data to db using add.php

Comment: When you manually executed the command it didn't write the temp&hum to the DB.  So you have a fundamental problem on the server side, before you even start involving an Arduino.  (Are you sure its not a firewall issue?)

Comment: I know on my router I have firewall turned off

Comment: I would suggest, that you give IP as another Parameter to the add.php and the insert-statement. With this you could test from where the call is made. If it is also 0. Then you got either a problem with the firewall as Matt stated, or it can be a probleml with the Variables of the add.php. (I don't know php so good)

Comment: POST data doesn't need a `?`. Also you can't get GET parameters (from URL), from the `$_POST` variable.

Comment: yes, yesterday I realized and fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I came to learn in my php code posted above, I am using `$_POST` variable when I should rather be using `$_GET`

In the PHP script, there are $_GET and $_POST variables that contain the data passed to the script, depending on the method used to to activate the script.

so using `$temp1=$_GET["temp1"];` and `$hum1=$_GET["hum1"];` fixes the problem.